# Is parsing a language with an ending delimiter (e.g. ';') more efficient than having none?

Tags: parsing, language-design

I am wondering about the effect of having an ending delimiter about performance (if it's a scripting language) and ease to parse languages.
Is it easier to parse a language that has one?
If it is and the language is a scripting language, does it make the language run commands faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any difference is going to be trivial.
This is because a language that doesn't use such end delimiters, do infact have them in the form of newline characters!!  These will then use special characters to mark that teh statement continues on to the next line.

A few do neither, but there, the end of the statement is implicit in the definition - eg. the close ')' at the end of a parameter list. If there's a comma (or nothing) then more parameters or a closed ')' will be expected on the next line.

In the big scheme of things, these small differences have a negligible effect on processing time. For script languages, you're going to have much bigger differences according to whether (or how much) a particular statement construct can be internally optimized.

Comment: Well, as an odd example, JavaScript doesn't *always* require newline characters, but it has funny rules about what they mean if semicolons aren't present. Having build JavaScript parsers, I can confirm the the presence or absence doesn't make a measurable difference in parsing time.

Comment: Right, so for what is probably one of the most convoluted examples, the overall effect is negligible.

Answer (score 2):

Performance-wise It doesn't matter.

If you think about it, there's always a delimiter, if it's not the ; then it's EndOfLine (\n)

So you're still parsing the code script the same way. The parser won't mind if it's a delimiter that's a visible character or invisible one.

The only thing that a visible delimiter is good for, is enabling the programmer to write multi-line script lines, which can be useful. Multi-lined script lines enable the programmer to write more coherent code in some cases. (Just parse the EndOfLine as a white space)

Answer (score 2):

All languages I'm aware of that don't require an explicit typed-out statement delimiter or terminator use line breaks instead - in a few cases, with the exception that line breaks inside parens, braces, brackets, etc. are ignored (implicit line continuation). A small difference, and its effect on parsing speed will heavily depend on the parser (or parser generator). It may be slightly harder to write a parser for if you allow implicit line continuations (because you have to distinguish between newlines and statement seperators - but this can be sorted out relatively early in the parsing process unless you invent incredibly complex rules for it).

But: Even if there was a huge difference, it wouldn't affect runtime performance. Unless for programs where it doesn't matter anyway since they're rather short and/or I/O-bound (or especially stupid implementations that refuse to build any IR and instead interpret from source as they go, using a poorly-written parser), parsing takes place at most once at startup (today's "scripting" languages mostly compile to bytecode and mostly cache that bytecode between runs) and is then shadowed by the time the program spends doing its actual pass. Don't make tradeoffs at language design for speed; or if so, do it properly as e.g. C.

A more interesting issue is explicit block delimiters vs. offside rule. The tokenizer can already solve this, but most parsing generators/libraries don't (easily) give you such a parser. A few do, and in that case the difference is negible, but it's not as widely supported as "free-form" langauges.